# Browser trying to save .xlsx file as .zip

Tags: html, apache, download, file-extension

A website running on Apache has the following innocuous line to link an .xlsx spreadsheet for download: `<a href='/files/files.xlsx'>Download</a>`

When I click it, Opera offers to download the file as a .zip instead. While .xlsx files are valid .zip files, I would prefer them to be downloaded as spreadsheets. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: What MIME type does your server send?

Comment: @Blender probably not the right one. How would I check? I'm using Apache+PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to `.htaccess` in the site's root directory solved the issue

```
# XLSX
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet .xlsx
```

Here's a good [sample .htaccess file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Sample_.htaccess_file) configured with various popular extensions MIME-type pairs.